# change log files output path for flink jobs that run on yarn

Tags: apache-flink, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

We have a few flink jobs that run on yarn. We would like to upload flink job logs to ELK to simplify debugging/analysis. Currently flink task managers write logs to `/mnt/flinklogs/$application_id/$container_id`. We want to have it write to a directory without `$applicatoin_id/$container_id` nested structure.

I tried with  `env.log.dir: /mnt/flink`. With this setting, the configuration is not passed correctly.

```
 -Dlog.file=/mnt/flinklogs/application_1560449379756_1312/\
    container_e02_1560449379756_1312_01_000619/taskmanager.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approche to solve this is using [yarn log aggregation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/yarn_setup.html#log-files) to write to log to disk and elastic  [filebit](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat)  to send them to elastic.

Comment: @MlkCode  thanks for the reply!  when the job has many containers and the amount of logs in GB level, using `yarn logs --applicationId ...` may take a while to get the logs.  we also cannot get logs of long running applications in this way.